# Fetching date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How to split date in select query of SQL Server 2008 ?
If you feed you feed current date in database and the type of that column in database is date time then It will store the date as well as time.If any one want to fetch only the date part from that column then what can he do.

I can use this query but it should not work.

```
SELECT DonorName, DATE(DateOfDonation) AS DateOfDonation 
FROM CreateDonorDetail;
```

it give error-

> 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I can use this code it can give me the proper result that i want.

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateOfDonation,101) AS DateOfDonation FROM CreateDonorDetail;

Comment: marc_s has given you your answer. I suggest you accept it

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2008 **has** a `DATE` datatype - but it's disabled if your database was upgraded from a SQL Server 2005, and you didn't change the database **compatibility level**.

Check your compatibility level like this:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = '-Your-database-name-here-'
```

If this compatibility level is `90`, it's set to SQL Server 2005 and you won't be able to use `DATE`. Update your compatibility level to 100:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

Now you should be able to use `DATE`:

```
SELECT 
    DonorName, 
    CAST(DateOfDonation AS DATE) AS DateOfDonation 
FROM CreateDonorDetail;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast as `Date` type:

```
SELECT DonorName, Cast(DateOfDonation as Date) AS DateOfDonation 
FROM CreateDonorDetail;
```

Comment: It will also give an error-                                                                     Type Date is not a defined system type.

Comment: Then you Are not using SQL Server 2008, because I can assure you Date datatype is defined.

Comment: That comment makes no sense.

Comment: marc_s has given you your answer. I suggest you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to SQL Server 2008 you colud use something like this:

```
SELECT DonorName, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DateOfDonation AS FLOAT)) AS datetime) AS DateOfDonation   FROM CreateDonorDetail
```

Comment: This cade will work but it can also give the date as well as time.I can't want time in result.

Comment: hello sir please give the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME

SELECT @DateTime = '2010/05/20 11:21:13'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DateTime ,105) AS Date

the result will be in dd-mm-yyyy format (105)

- Hope it will helps

mark as answer if it helped

Comment: the data type of that column in data base is still datetime then no need to convert it.

Comment: select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreatedDate,101) as Date from BE_CostCentre_Mstr                   ... try like this .. hope it will helps